# React Hooks with ReactCSSTransitionGroup not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following dummy project which contains a dropdown menu:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropdown-class-wtzuf

(click the upper left button with "+")

Here is the source code for: `src\components\header\header.jsx`.

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.scss'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      menuActive: false
    };
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    let menuState = !this.state.menuActive;
    this.setState({
      menuActive: menuState
    });
  }

  render() {
    let menu;
    if (this.state.menuActive) {
      menu = <div className="dropdown">
                <ul>
                  <li>First Item </li>
                  <li>Second Item </li>
                  <li>Third Item </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
    } else {
      menu = "";
    }
    return ( 
      <div id="menu">
        <button href="#" onClick = { this.toggleMenu }>+</button> 
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="menu" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}> 
          {menu} 
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

**My goal is:** convert the example above to use `React Hooks`.

I did an experiment on this link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropdown-hooks-8nvut

but didn't work.

Here is what I tried:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './header.scss'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

function Header() {

  const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => { setMenuActive(!menuActive) };

  let menu = () => menuActive? <div className="dropdown">
                              <ul>
                                <li>First Item </li>
                                <li>Second Item </li>
                                <li>Third Item </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>: ""
  return ( 
    <div id="menu">
      <button href="#" onClick = { toggleMenu }>+</button> 
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="menu" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}> 
        {menu}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
  )

}

export default Header;
```

with the last code the dropdown menu doesn't open.

Could you please, provide back the code that do the trick?

If possible maybe you can provide the forked `codesandbox.io`.

Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the code in sandbox, i doubt the issue is related to the `css` , because hooks are working fine

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the code on Header.jsx & double check your menu

On your first link with the class component, here's the code

```
menu = <div className="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>First Item </li>
    <li>Second Item </li>
    <li>Third Item </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, when reimplementing it with hooks, you initialized menu as a function

```
menu = () => menuActive ?
  <div className="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>First Item </li>
      <li>Second Item </li>
      <li>Third Item </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
: null;
```

If you wanted it as a function, you should invoke the `menu` function

```
return ( 
  <div id="menu">
    <button href="#" onClick={toggleMenu}>+</button> 
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="menu" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}> 
      {menu()}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
);
```